# Member Variables and Local Variables

Tags: vb.net

I came across the following definition of MEMBER & LOCAL variables in MSDN documentation which reads like this:

A local variable is one that is declared within a procedure.

A member variable is a member of a Visual Basic type; it is declared at module level, inside a class, structure, or module, but not within any procedure internal to that class, structure, or module.

So based upon the above definition I understand that in the following code, variables "a,c and _field" are member variables while variable "b,d" are local variables. Can someone pls confirm if I am right or wrong?

```
Module Program

    Dim a As Integer = 5 'a is a member variable
    Sub Main()
        Dim b As Integer = 10 'b is not a member variable. It is a local variable
    End Sub
End Module

Class test
    Dim c As Integer 'c is a member variable
    Private _field As String '_field is a member variable
    Sub check()
        Dim d As Integer 'd is a local variable
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Easy to remember: member variables are variables declared in the scope of a type(class, interface=property, module). But i would refer to them with the general term "Member" since "Variables" is slightly wrong if you refer to fields and properties. Types can have several members like properties or methods. Methods can contain local variables. So yes, you are right.